# Nusoap library integration with codeigniter shows Unsupported HTTP response status 404 Not Found Error

Tags: php, codeigniter, nusoap

I am using Nusoap library in codeigniter. My code works fine in localhost as well as on server before i make new folder for my testing purpose. But now in testing folder it gives error like this.

I'm receiving this Error:

> `HTTP Error: Unsupported HTTP response status 404 Not Found` 
>   `(soapclient->response has contents of the response)`

I have searched solution [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20277451/why-sometime-can-get-error-404-not-found-soapclient-response-has-contents-of-t) and [Here](http://forum.nusphere.com/unsupported-http-response-status-404-not-found-t4759.html) but it shows that endpoint is not set for client. On my side, when I print my object it has the endpoint value... What do I do wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I can't connect the URL(http://carvilshoe.cz.cc/index.wsdl.php?wsdl) from my web browser too. I think you have to check your WebService status is online.